# Trying to loop through different surveys in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to loop through different sections in my survey in python to calculate the total time taken to answer each specific section (there are three sections: Warehouse, psychometrics and healthcare).

My data is in a csv format and for each section in the survey, time data is displayed in 9 columns that start with a common suffix (ie, 'sectionname'.timedata). So to calculate the time spent in each section, I wrote a line of code which sums up all the values in those columns for the specific section:

```
Surveyresp['Warehouse_time'] = Surveyresp[[col for col in Surveyresp.columns if col.startswith('Warehouse.timedata')]].sum(axis=1)

Surveyresp['Psychometrics_time'] = Surveyresp[[col for col in Surveyresp.columns if col.startswith('Psychometric.timedata')]].sum(axis=1)

Surveyresp['Healthcare_time'] = Surveyresp[[col for col in Surveyresp.columns if col.startswith('Healthcare.timedata')]].sum(axis=1)
```

My question is, is there a way I can just loop through these 3 surveys to make this change?

I tried starting the loop:

```
Surveys = ['Warehouse.timedata', 'Psychometric.timedata']

for i in Surveys:
   print(i)
   Surveyresp['i_time'] = Surveyresp[[col for col in Surveyresp.columns if col.startswith('i')]].sum(axis=1)
```

But all this loop does is create one new variable (that is, 'i_time'). What am I doing wrong with this loop?

Thanks!

Comment: your code is replacing value of `i_time` for each survey, so it's only have value of last survey, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm trying to create 3 new time variables for each section (so, warehouse, psychometrics and healthcare) that is a resulting sum of the time columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of the loop was almost correct. :)

```
Surveys = ['Warehouse.timedata', 'Psychometric.timedata']

for i in Surveys:
   print(i)
   colum_name = i.split(".")
   Surveyresp[] = Surveyresp[[col for col in Surveyresp.columns if col.startswith('i')]].sum(axis=1)
```

But it should look like this to correctly loop over all columns

```
Surveys = ['Warehouse', 'Psychometric']

for i in Surveys:
    print(i)
    Surveyresp[i+"_time"] = Surveyresp[[col for col in Surveyresp.columns if col.startswith(i+".timedata")]].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this worked perfectly :)